# Add a local application to syslog excluded from /var/log/messages

Tags: syslog

I have an application which logs to syslog facility local1. I would like to configure syslog to send all local1 messages to a log file separate from /var/log/messages -- that turned out to be easy. But the messages are *also* going to /var/log/messages. is there some way to tell syslog to send *.info to /var/log/messages but exclude local1.info? (Something like *^loacl1.info ?)

syslog.conf:

```
#kern.*                                                 /dev/console

*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages

authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure

local0.notice;local0.debug;mail.*;mail.none;mail.info;local0.info /var/log/maillog

cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron

*.emerg                                                 *

uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler

local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log

#My Custom App Logging
local1.*                                             /var/log/application.log
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try replacing

```
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages
```

by

```
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none;local1.!=info                /var/log/messages
```

This will log message that match : any facility with level info AND facility not mail AND facility not authpriv **AND facility local1 execpt when level is info**.

Comment: Ah ha -- thanks to your edited post I now see what I want is local1.none, not local1.!=info. I didn't realize what the behavior of .none was.

Comment: @Radius: Shouldn't that be 'local1.none', not 'local1.!=info'?

Also, I believe that 'local1.!=info' doesn't work with all Syslog daemons. 'local1.none' is more universal.

Comment: @Stefan, the original request was to exclude local1.info not all local1 message. So local1.!=info is the right syntax. But in fact Josh need was to exclude all local1 messages (from his comment), so in this case local1.none is the right syntax

Answer (score 2):

You should use either

```
#My Custom App Logging
local1.*                                             /var/log/application.log
& ~
```

for syslog or

```
#My Custom App Logging
local1.*                                             /var/log/application.log
& stop
```

for rsyslog 7+ to prevent the log message from being processed further. Make sure this comes *before* the default rules which log `*.*` to /var/log/syslog.

Answer (score 0):

just a compliment to @radius answer

based on rsyslog documentation
https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/filters.html

> You can specify multiple facilities with the same priority pattern in
> one statement using the comma (“,’’) operator

I prefer to use the below line

```
*.info;mail, authpriv, cron.none;local1.!=info                /var/log/messages
```

BTW This will log messages that match : any facility with level info and higher, for limiting it to only info you can use

> You may precede every priority with an equals sign (“=’’) to specify
> only this single priority and not any of the above

```
*.=info;mail, authpriv, cron.none;local1.!=info                /var/log/messages
```