# How can I log iptables in Ubuntu just in /var/log/firewall with rsyslogd

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, log-files, logging, rsyslog

I am using ubuntu 10.10. with iptables! I want to log my firewall drops in the file /var/log/firewall and **NOT** in any other logfile.

So I added the following line to my file: /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf:

```
#iptables Log
kern.warning    /var/log/firewall.log
```

This way my drops and logs from iptables are logging into the right file!

Now i dont know what to add to not log the drops in the other files.. At this time it write every drop in /var/log/messages /var/log/kern.log and /var/log/syslog

Heeeelp :)

I found this one : [Add a local application to syslog excluded from /var/log/messages](https://serverfault.com/questions/45402/add-a-local-application-to-syslog-excluded-from-var-log-messages) but it doesnt work.. Maybe because its Rsyslogd in Ubuntu 10.10?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a discard action after the iptables log, but before the other logs.

```
kern.warning   /var/log/firewall.log
kern.warning   ~
*.*            /var/log/messages
```

Comment: What does `~` mean? (the rsyslog manual is a little vague).

Comment: @Stefan: `rsyslog.conf(5)` man page, **ACTIONS** section, **Discard** subsection.